# How to obtain this Pohozaev identity for the Gross-Pitaevskii equation?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

The Gross-Pitaveskii equation (after plugging in the traveling wave ansatz and writing in moving frame coordinates) reads \begin{equation} ic\partial_1 v +\Delta v +v(1-\vert v \vert^2)=0.    \end{equation}

Assume $v$ is a solution on $\Omega_n^N=[-n\pi,n\pi]^N$ and $v$ is $2\pi n$-periodic in every component.

In [1,p.623] the authors give Pohozaev's formula for $v$ without any proof \begin{align} \frac{N-2}{2} \int_{\Omega_n^N} \vert \nabla v \vert^2+\frac{N}{4}\int_{\Omega_n^N} (1-\vert v \vert^2)^2 - c\frac{N-1}{v} \int_{\Omega_n^N} \langle Jv, \zeta_1 \rangle \\ = n\pi \int_{\partial \Omega_n^N} \left( \frac{\vert \nabla v \vert^2}{2} + \frac{(1-\vert v \vert^2)^2}{4} \right) - \int_{\partial \Omega_n^N} \partial_\nu v \left( \sum_{j=1}^N x_j \partial_j v \right). \end{align}

Here the 2-form \begin{equation} Jv \equiv \sum_{1 \leq 1 < j \leq N} (\partial_i v \times \partial_j v) dx_i \wedge dx_j \end{equation} denotes the Jacobian of $v$ and $\zeta_1$ is the 2-form defined by \begin{equation} \zeta_1(x) \equiv - \frac{2}{N-1} \sum_{i=2}^N x_i dx_1 \wedge dx_i. \end{equation} Finally, $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ stands for the scalar product of 2-forms.

**My Question is**:

> How do you obtain this "Pohozaev's formula"?

From what I have read on the internet already, it seems like you have to multiply the Gross-Pitaevskii equation by $(x|\nabla v(x))$ or similar and integrate by parts. But this doesn't help me too much. How do the 2-forms appear? I'm completly lost. Any hint would be much appreciated!

---

[1] Béthuel, F., P. Gravejat und J. C. Saut: Travelling waves for the Gross- Pitaevskii equation. II. Comm. Math. Phys., 285(2):567–651, 2009.

Comment: Small comment: the equation you wrote down is _not_ the Gross-Pitaevskii (also note the spelling) in any coordinates. It is the reduced equation under a traveling wave ansatz $v(t,x_1, x_2, \ldots) = v(0, x_1 - ct,x_2, x_3, \ldots)$.

Comment: Second comment, the integrals in the second line should be **boundary integrals** along $\partial\Omega$, not interior ones.

Comment: @WillieWong Corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you multiply by $x_i\partial_i v$ and integrate (summation convention where repeated indices are always summed from $1$ to $N$ is in effect throughout). Let me do them term by term (for ease of notation I assume $v$ is real. Minor changes with complex conjugations will get your the complex case.)

$$ \begin{align}
\int_\Omega -\triangle v x_i \partial_i v & = \int_\Omega -\partial_j\partial_j v x_i \partial_i v \\
&= - \int_{\partial\Omega} \nu_j\partial_j v x_i \partial_i v + \int_\Omega \partial_j v (\delta_{ij} \partial_i v + x_i \partial_i \partial_j v) \\
&= - \int_{\partial\Omega}\partial_\nu v x_i \partial_i v + \int_\Omega |\nabla v|^2 + \frac12 \int_\Omega x_i \partial_i |\nabla v|^2 \\
&= - \int_{\partial\Omega}\partial_\nu v x_i \partial_i v + \int_\Omega |\nabla v|^2 - \frac{N}{2} \int_{\Omega} |\nabla v|^2 + \frac12 \int_{\partial\Omega} \nu_i x_i |\nabla v|^2 \end{align}$$

where $\nu$ is the unit normal vector to the boundary. Using that $\Omega$ is a box $[-n\pi,n\pi]^N$ you have that $\nu_i x_i = n\pi$ on the boundary.

$$\begin{align}
\int_\Omega - v(1-v^2) x_i \partial_i v &= -\frac12 \int_{\Omega} (1-v^2) x_i \partial_i v^2 \\
&= \frac12 \int_{\Omega}(1-v^2) x_i \partial_i(1-v^2) \\
&= \frac14 \int_{\Omega} x_i \partial_i (1-v^2)^2 \\
&= - \frac{N}4 \int_{\Omega} (1-v^2)^2 + \frac14 \int_{\partial\Omega} \nu_i x_i (1-v^2)^2 \end{align}$$

We've already taken care of the majority of the terms. The remaining one (the one involving the two form) comes from the $\partial_1$ term. This last derivation follows from Remark 4.2 which starts on page 615 of the paper you are referring to.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have to think about this for a while...

Comment: Thank you so so much! That indeed helped me a lot! I think the first two lines miss a $\sum_{j}$ and the $N$ appears only after taking $\sum_i$, right? Then $\nu x= n\pi$ (on specific parts of the boundary $\nu_i x_i =0$). What I still don't fully understand is the $\partial_1$ term. But I'm on it...

Comment: ah, I didn't realise you are not used to the Einstein summation convention. Yes, all repeated indices are implicitly summed.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the $\partial_1$ term. I compute $\sum_{k=1}^N \int (ic\partial_1 v)\cdot (x_k  \partial_k v) = \sum_{k=1}^N \int c x_k (i\partial_1 v_1 \partial_k v_1 - \partial_1 v_1 \partial_k v_2 - \partial_1 v_2 \partial_k v_1 - i \partial_1 v_2 \partial_k v_2)$ and $\int \langle Ju , \zeta_1 \rangle  = -\frac{2}{N-1}  \int \sum_{k=2}^N (\partial_1 u \times \partial_k u) x_k$. That does not seem to fit. Especially because the first sums starts at $k=1$ and the second one at $k=2$.

Comment: For that term you must use the fact that $v$ is complex valued, unlike the rest of the terms. Consider $$\int (i\partial_1 v)(x_k\partial_k \bar{v}) + (\overline{i\partial_1 v})(x_k \partial_k v) $$ where the multiplication is just the usual multiplication of complex numbers and the bar on top is complex conjugation. (In reality, you have to do this too for all of the rest of the terms.)

Comment: Sorry my questions become increasingly stupid. Indeed (after some calculations) your term equals $-c\frac{2}{N-1} \langle Ju,\zeta_1 \rangle$ and this is exactly what I want. But how do you get this term? If I take $v=v_1+iv_2$ to be complex and compute $(ic\partial_1 (v_1+iv_2))\cdot (x_k \partial_k (v_1+iv_2))$ I get the result in my last comment. This is different from your term. What is my mistake? Do you instead take $(i \partial_1 v) \times (x_k \partial v)$ identifying $\mathbb{C}\simeq \mathbb{R}^2$? But this would be  $\frac{1}{2}$ of your term...

Comment: @mjb: no, the trick is that when $v$ is complex valued, the "natural" inner product to take is the sesquilinear one; this part you did. But to get a real-valued identity you have to take the "real part" of both sides. What I did was simply $$\Re\langle f,g\rangle = \frac12 \left(\langle f,g\rangle + \overline{\langle f,g\rangle}\right) = \frac12 \left( \langle f,g\rangle + \langle g,f\rangle \right) $$ where $\langle,\rangle$ is a sesquilinear inner product.

Comment: Notice that when $f,g$ are both real in the expression above, $\langle f,g\rangle = \langle g,f\rangle$. So in the case where the coefficients are all real (in the two identities I did for you), I can do the derivations assuming that $v$ is real, and then just combine the contributions from the real part and the imaginary part together appropriately to get the identity for complex valued $v$. But in the case where the coefficients is possibly complex (you have $ic$ which is purely imaginary), you necessarily have to go through the whole shebang and "properly" compute as in the comment before.

Comment: In other words, all along we should be trying to compute $$\Re \langle ic \partial_1 v + \triangle v + v(1 - |v|^2),x_k \partial_k v\rangle = 0$$ But for the two terms I did explicitly I can cheat a little bit on the computation by treating $v$ as if it were real because the coefficients for those terms are real. If you are not comfortable with the "cheat" I invite you to redo the two terms I showed you, now dropping the assumption that $v$ is real, and do it using the expression above.

Comment: Now I get it! Thank you very very much! I'm extremly grateful for all you effort! I'll reward the bounty to your answer as soon as possible (~23h).

Comment: You are welcome!